# Disable Auto-Tab in Visual Studio via a dat file

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, syntax-highlighting, masm

I wrote a dat file for when I'm writing assembly to give me some syntax highlighting, the problem I am running into is that one way to do a comment in MASM is to use a semicolon and you typically tab a fair bit away from the actual code before you write the comment (at least I do). Well whenever I do this, it messes up all of the formatting in the .asm file because it tries to format the document whenever it sees a semicolon, I am wondering is there a way to turn off auto tabbing and other stuff via a dat file? I just know how to load a dat file that tells the editor some words to highlight, that's it.

Thanks in advance for any input on this :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can export the specific settings for a certain project and then import it later. This will save `.vssettings` XML format file.

Just define you tab setting before in **Options** dialog from the **Tools** menu, selecting the **Text Editor** -> **Your prefered language**-> **Formatting** -> **General** page, and unchecking relevant check- box ( in your case tabbing).

Then in **Tools** > **Import and Export Settings** , export the settings.

I hope it sort your issue.